# How do I connect the front-end interface of gatsby to change parameters in gatsby-config plugins so I can render new data from plugins that are APIs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am using the gatsby-source-twitter plugin to render data for a specific user on one of my routes (user_tweets.js) in gatsby. Here is the code for the plugin:

gatsby-config.js

```
    {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-twitter`,
    options: {
        q: `from:@elonmusk`,
        credentials: {
            consumer_key: "xxx",
            consumer_secret: "xxx",
            bearer_token: "xxx"
        },
        tweet_mode: "extended",
        result_type: "latest"
      },
    },
```

Right now, if I want to render the tweets of a different user on my tweets page, I have to change the query of the API manually everytime in gatsby-config.

Is there a way to link gatsby-config.js to my user_tweets page so someone can input their own query and new data will be rendered from graphql on that page?

Here's what user_tweets.js looks like and Layout is basically an input field where I want to enter a different twitter handle and have it rendered.

user_tweets.js

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

export default ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <p>Users tweets:</p>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {data.allTweet.edges.map(({ node }, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{node.full_text}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allTweet {
        edges {
            node {
                created_at
                full_text
                user {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
`
```